# C function to find how many times a number reappears in a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

So I wrote this function in C that takes as a parameter a pointer that stores the address of the start of a linked list that contains several numbers(integers). It then returns the number of times a number reappears in the list. For example 7777 will return 3 since the number 7 appears 3 more times. The number 8233982 also 3 etc.
This is the code:

```
int countRedun(struct digit * start) {
    struct digit * front = start;
    struct digit * back = start->next;
    int i, a[10];
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        a[i] = 0;
    } 
    while (front != NULL) {
        while (back != NULL) {
            if (front->num == back->num) {
                a[front->num] ++;
            }
            back = back->next;
        }
        front = front->next;
        while (a[front->num] > 0) {
            front = front->next;
        }
        if (front != NULL) {
            back = front->next;
        }
    }
    int s = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        s += a[i];
    }
    return s;
}
```

I know that it's simpler if the list was sorted but let's consider this case. When I try to run this it says segmentation fault. Where is the mistake? The idea is that I have 2 pointers, *front* that starts from the beginning of the list and *back* that starts from the second node of the list and checks the next nodes and compares them to the number that is stored in address front. When *back* reaches the end of the list *front* goes to the next node only if that address contains a number that has not been counted before, else it goes to the next node etc.

The linked list:

```
struct digit {
    int num;
    struct digit *next; 
};
```

Comment: You are in several places moving front to next but not checking for null. However, first consider why you doing this such a complicated manner - just iterate through the list and count the number of occurrences of each digit in the list by incrementing the array for that number, then iterate over the array and total the number of repetitions based on the counts. (if the count is greater than one, then the number of repetitions is one less)

Comment: OT: `a[10] = { 0 };` will set all elements to zero, i.e. then you don't need the loop.

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed it**

```
int countRedun(struct digit * start) {
struct digit * front = start;
struct digit * back = start->next;
int i, a[10] = { 0 };
while (front != NULL) {
    while (back != NULL) {
        if (front->num == back->num) {
            a[front->num] ++;
        }
        back = back->next;
    }
    front = front->next;
    int f = 0;
    if (front != NULL) {
        while (f != 1 && a[front->num] > 0) {
            front = front->next;
            if (front == NULL) {
                f = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if (front != NULL) {
        back = front->next;
    }
}
int s = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    s += a[i];
}
return s;}
```

Checked each time I moved the front pointer for the NULL case and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm seems to be more complex than needed. Use a single list iteration to count the number of times each number occur. Then it's simple to calculate the "repeated count" afterwards.

Like:

```
int countRedun(struct digit * start) {
    int a[10] = { 0 };
    while (start != NULL) {
        assert(start->num >= 0 && start->num < 10);
        a[start->num]++;
        start = start->next;
    }

    int s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (a[i]) s = s + a[i] - 1;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: why use assert? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @konxanth assert is just to make clear that the numbers in the list must be in the range [0:9]. As long as that is true, the assert does nothing. In principle it can just be deleted if you don't want that check.